# Django Translation Not working

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I have a view which has the following code.  I need to translate am and pm to arabic

which is display by %p.  I called this in template by ajax.I tried by doing

`_strptime("%I:%M %p")`,bit its not working.  Here this code strftime`("%I:%M %p")` is used

to display time 1:00AM to 2:00 PM.  How will i translate this:

```
result['start'] = datetime.strptime((str(delivery_area_timing.start)[:-3]),   

"%H:%M").strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

Ajax code:

```
$("#shop_work_hours").html(data.start+' {% trans 'to' %} '+data.end);
```

Comment: Which OS is this code running on?

Answer (score 0):

This is not done by Translation in Django. You will have to set the locale for printing a date in that language. For e.g. printing date in Arabic (must be supported by your OS):

```
import time
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'arabic')
print (time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```